# Loop tuning- I need to re-write this Java program snippet

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

My goal is to build a pyramid as such:

[image: Example]

I am supposed to use a loop (for or while) to get this effect. I have accomplished this with the following code:

```
package finalprob1;
public class FinalProb1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int row = 1;
        int input = 6;
        int rowcount = 11;
        int blocknum = 1, blockperrow = 1;
        while (row <= rowcount)
        {
          while(blocknum < blockperrow)
          {
            System.out.print(input * blocknum + " ");
            blocknum = blocknum +1 ; 
          }
          blocknum = 1;
          System.out.println();
          blockperrow = blockperrow + 1;
          row = row +1;
        }       
    } // END OF MAIN
} // END OF CLASS
```

The code is very messy.. I am sure that there is a very simple way to get this done with two loops but I cant seem to figure it out. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This kind of question is better ask in [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be done simply like this

```
 for(int i = 1;i<11;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
      System.out.print((6*j)+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your code as below.

```
int size = 10;
for(int row = 1; row <= size; row++) {
    for(int col = 1;col <= row; col++) {
        System.out.print( 6*col + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
public class Test {

    private static final String sp = " "; // space

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTriangle(6, 60);

    }

    public static void printTriangle(int num, int maxMultiple) {

        int itr = maxMultiple / num;

        for (int i = 1; i <= itr; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(num * j + sp);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```